# Objective C drawRect in subview not called after add it to super view and setNeedsDisplay

Tags: subview, drawrect, superview, setneedsdisplay

I have a view: **DragView** and a view: **GameAreaView**, and declare **GameAreaView** in **GameViewController**.

The problem is that my custom subview: DragView did not drawRect as expected, there is nothing drawn in super view.

**GameViewController.m**

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
...... get touch point , but haven't use it

// Initialise a dragView when user touches in gameAreaView
DragView *agentDragger = [[DragView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,     
50, 50)];

[self.gameAreaView addSubview:agentDragger];

[[self gameAreaView] setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

**GameAreaView.m**

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"I am GameAreaView Rect!!");
}
```

**DragView.m**
-(id) initwithFrame::(CGRect)frame

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"1.Hi i am in if ");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

   [MyStyleKitAgent drawAgentNodeWithFrame:_frame
                        longPressed:_isLongPressed
                               vname:_name
                             pressed:_isPressed];


// Test for draw lines
NSLog(@"I am in DragView");
```

But if I **change** **initwithFrame** to **initwithImage**

```
-(id) initWithImage:(UIImage *) anImage
{
    self = [super initWithImage:anImage];
    return self;
}
```

The subview with image displayed in GameAreaView, which did not use drawRect.

I also tried use **setNeesDisplayInRect**, nothing changes.

Why drawRect in **DragView.m** did not called when using -(id)initwithFrame?
Why this happens? 
And how to fix it?

Comment: where did you call the drag view ?

Comment: make a property of your drag view and use [self.dragview setneedsdisplay];

Comment: I called it in -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: I tried you way, but still drawrect in DragView not called.

Comment: What I want is that once user touch the GameAreaView, then create a DragView in that point. I did not add the view of class DragView in main.storyboard, because I think it is created dynamically. Is that the problem?

Comment: in touches method, you are calling the view of the game view controller but not the drag view

Comment: you need to call setNeedsDisplay on your subview not on your main view

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your subview by setNeedsDisplay not your main view

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //...... get touch point , but haven't use it

// Initialise a dragView when user touches in gameAreaView
 DragView *agentDragger = [[DragView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,     
  50, 50)];

 [self.gameAreaView addSubview:agentDragger];

  [agentDragger setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering，I tried again the code as you write, but still not called drawRect in dragView.